# Program doesn't work when configured as a systemd service

Tags: c, linux, systemd, xlib

I'm trying to write a program that can run as a service on Linux.
It mainly sends and receives data with a server, receives a `.so` file sent by the server, and uses `dlopen()` to execute the functions inside.

It works when I manually enable it through the `sudo` command.
I tried to write a `systemd` file to make it boot automatically, however that doesn't work. For example, using the screen capture function of `Xlib` gets an all black picture.

I've tried to redirect the debugging information to the file, but I can only get the debugging information of the main program; I can't get the operation information of the plug-in. I am sure that the function of the plug-in has been executed, but there are errors in the execution process.

The result of its program is that the screenshot content is completely black, and the connection is automatically disconnected after client sending the screenshot. It may be that a segment fault is encountered at the client, but this has not happened when I start the program manually

Any ideas?

This is my service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=just for test

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/mnt/main.debug
Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS,DISPLAY,WAYLAND_DISPLAY(new added)

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to start service by `systemctl start ps-hak.service`,the error message is this:

```
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl start ps-hak.service
^[OAJob for ps-hak.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status ps-hak.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl start ps-hak.service^C
a@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status ps-hak.service
● ps-hak.service - just for test
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ps-hak.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2021-08-03 19:20:18 PDT; 18s ago
  Process: 2662 ExecStart=/mnt/main.debug (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Aug 03 19:20:08 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting just for test...
Aug 03 19:20:08 ubuntu main.debug[2662]: 
Aug 03 19:20:08 ubuntu main.debug[2662]: [DEBUG|main.cpp:40 (main)]: WAYLAND_DIS
Aug 03 19:20:08 ubuntu main.debug[2662]: DISPLAY=(null)
Aug 03 19:20:08 ubuntu main.debug[2662]: 
Aug 03 19:20:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: ps-hak.service: Control process exited, code=
Aug 03 19:20:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start just for test.
Aug 03 19:20:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: ps-hak.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 03 19:20:18 ubuntu systemd[1]: ps-hak.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

I can only sure that the environment of the program is wrong, i have tried to add `Environment=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS,DISPLAY,WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, but it doesn't make sense.

I made a small program for debugging SYSTEMd. The code is as follows.
When I manually enable it, it can normally generate screenshots, but after I register as a service service, it cannot work normally. There is even no file generation in the specified directory, but there is no error message in `systemctl status test`.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#pragma pack (1)
typedef struct BitMAPFILEHEADER 
{
    short    bfType;
    int    bfSize;
    short    bfReserved1;
    short    bfReserved2;
    int   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct BitMAPINFOHEADER
{
    int  biSize;
    int   biWidth;
    int   biHeight;
    short   biPlanes;
    short   biBitCount;
    int  biCompression;
    int  biSizeImage;
    int   biXPelsPerMeter;
    int   biYPelsPerMeter;
    int  biClrUsed;
    int  biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;

void saveXImageToBitmap(const char* filename,XImage *pImage)
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader;
    FILE *fp;
    memset(&bmpFileHeader, 0, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    memset(&bmpInfoHeader, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    bmpFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;
    bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
    int biBitCount =32;
    int dwBmpSize = ((pImage->width * biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * pImage->height;

    // DEBUG("size of short:%d\r\n",(int)sizeof(short));
    // DEBUG("size of int:%d\r\n",(int)sizeof(int));
    // DEBUG("size of long:%d\r\n",(int)sizeof(long));
    // DEBUG("dwBmpSize:%d\r\n",(int)dwBmpSize);
    // DEBUG("BITMAPFILEHEADER:%d\r\n",(int)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    // DEBUG("BITMAPINFOHEADER:%d\r\n",(int)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) +  dwBmpSize;

    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = pImage->width;
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = pImage->height;
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = - bmpInfoHeader.biHeight;  // important,otherwise the pic will be reversed
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = biBitCount;
    bmpInfoHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bmpInfoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    fp = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fp == NULL)
        return;

    fwrite(&bmpFileHeader, sizeof(bmpFileHeader), 1, fp);
    fwrite(&bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader), 1, fp);
    fwrite(pImage->data, dwBmpSize, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

int CaptureDesktop(const char* filename)
{
    Window desktop;
    Display* dsp;
    XImage* img;

    int screen_width;
    int screen_height;
    dsp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);/* Connect to a local display */
    if(NULL==dsp)
    {
        // DEBUG("%s,%s\n","CaptureDesktop","Cannot connect to local display");
        return 0;
    }
    desktop = RootWindow(dsp,0);/* Refer to the root window */
    if(0==desktop)
    {
        // DEBUG("%s,%s\n","CaptureDesktop","cannot get root window");
        return 0;
    }

    /* Retrive the width and the height of the screen */
    screen_width = DisplayWidth(dsp,0);
    screen_height = DisplayHeight(dsp,0);
    // DEBUG("%d %d\n",screen_width,screen_height);

    img = XGetImage(dsp,desktop,0,0,screen_width,screen_height,~0,ZPixmap);

    saveXImageToBitmap(filename,img);
   
    XCloseDisplay(dsp);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    CaptureDesktop("/home/a/out.bmp");
    return 0;
}
```

Operation process:

```
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl enable test
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl start test
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl status test
● test.service - just for test
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2021-08-03 20:17:57 PDT; 5s ago
  Process: 2501 ExecStart=/mnt/test (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 03 20:17:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting just for test...
Aug 03 20:17:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started just for test.
lines 1-7/7 (END)
```

I can confirm that there is a problem with the environment variable of the service started by systemd, but the applet should work normally without environment variable, but as a service, it does not work normally.
I think the main problem may not be the screenshot function, because other functions have similar results.

Comment: It would help if you'd add the contents of the service file and what it's supposed to do to your question.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Showing code is a lot more helpful than describing it. Please [edit] your question to include a minimal program that demonstrates the problem so we can run it ourselves. Show us your C code and systemd `.service` file. This will help us answer your question better, and will also help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: I added the content of .service file, thanks

Comment: I infer from the fact that you're talking about screenshots that the program in question produces some sort of GUI display.  That's very unusual for a system service, and I can think of several reasons for it not to work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe my expression is not clear enough. The screenshot is only one of the functions, and other functions cannot be executed normally too. For example, file browsing, I can't get the debugging information of the plug-in. I only know that the plug-in quit running without sending any information.

Comment: We can't debug a program we don't have access to. I suggest you make a new, tiny test program that mimics one particular feature of this monolithic program and see if you can get it to run as a service. If you can, great, rinse and repeat with another feature; if not, post the code here and we'll help. This will take some time, perhaps hours.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Nice idea, i will try it.

Comment: @Yatogami, the fact that Xlib is involved in any way might well be enough to cause trouble when you try to launch the program as a system service.  But as John K said, we cannot debug this effectively for you.  We need to have code, and in particular, a [mre],

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call Xlib from that kind of service because it is not attached to a user session. The only kind of service that could reasonably use Xlib is a user-login service.

If you check the envrionment variables, DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY will be blank. That's the immediate failure reason. Filling them both with the "right" values will allow it to work. If you manage to find them, `setenv(3)` will set them and Xlib will pick them up. You could play tricks as root and try to track down the stuff for the current X session, but that's a vector-scalar problem. I run multiple X sessions. Which one's the right one?

Comment: I didn't call Xlib in the service. It only has one basic socket to interact with the server. When a screenshot is needed, the server sends the. So file to the client, and then the client calls the corresponding function through dlopen(). Is that the problem?

Comment: If this were the problem, Xvfb (virtual X server for headless setups) could be helpful. Maybe need to write a script to setup everything properly.

Comment: @Yatogami: Your code calls Xlib in a direct path from main(). Did you mean to upload something else?

Comment: @Joshua It's actually a function just written for testing, but I just tried other lightweight functions, such as obtaining the file name under a path. They can work normally.
However, when I integrate into the service, I send the corresponding so file through the server, but the corresponding function cannot be executed normally.
If it is not started as a service but from the terminal, it can normally perform the corresponding functions after receiving the so file.
Very strange.

Comment: @Yatogami: I'd recommend you stop sending .so files from the server. That's just bad design even if it did work.

Answer (score 1):

In general, not knowing about anything (like the answer suggesting the the missing X server to use), an approach I would try is to instead of running your `/mnt/main.debug` directly run it with [strace](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html): `strace -f -o /tmp/main.debug.strace.log /mnt/main.debug`. The `-o` will specify the output file, which maybe is not needed if systemd collects the output in a convenient way. The `-f` option is useful if you fork and wish to collect information from the child processes as well. Very often the output from `strace` gives very helpful indication where a program is failing. You are able to see stuff like failing system calls, content of files read and all the files that were attempted to be read, and all kind of things how the program is interacting with the system behind your back. You can compare the output to that of running your program under `strace` outside of systemd and see what it succeeds doing that does not work in the systemd service context.

Another thing to try is to enable debug symbols and core dumping. Please refer to the your Linux distro (or perhaps systemd) documentation how to enable them in the system or refer to [proc(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [core(5)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) manual pages. Then you can use `gdb` to investigate the core file and see the stack trace (or traces if the app is multithreaded). Likely you will have the exact line in your program where it crashed. Or perhaps it is bad pointer because something was not initialized properly due to earlier failure. It will help to reduce the optimization flags (e.g. `-O3` changed with `-O1` or even something more debug friendly) to get better stack traces (but please do verify that the program still crashes after building with safer compiler options).

Comment: Nice idea.That's a good way to debug the program, but it's too detailed to read for me. I'm trying to analyze it

Comment: `strace` log will show the system calls called, including details like arguments and return values and if you add options then the complete contents of the file reads etc. It may seem at first look a bit daunting, but this is only because the beginning contains some magickery related to dynamic linking. If you know C then it is not that complicated, especially as you need to typically focus only on the last lines where you see failures (and search backwards from there using file names and file descriptors or whatnot related to the failures).